# Atiyah-Macdonald Remarks after Theorem 4.5

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

[image]
[image]

---

I'm not sure how to see these remarks. For this first remark, is this not directly from the very last line of the proof without any further need to invoke 4.4?

For the second remark,the annhilator of $\overline{x}=\{y\mid \overline{xy}=\overline{0}\}$.The radical of this is then $\{y\mid \overline{xy^n}=\overline{0}\}$. This is then  $\{y\mid {xy^n}\in \mathfrak{a}\}$. I can't see how to use that if this is prime it is equal to one of the $p_i$.

---

Here is Lemma 4.4 for added context

[image]

Comment: Correct on the first remark. For the second remark, how is the annihilator of an element written in the notation of the ideal quotient? Hint: If $y$ annihilates $x$, then what is the behaviour of $y$ with respect to $(x)$?

Comment: If $y$ annihilates $x$ then $y$ also annihilates the ideal $(x)$. I'm still not seeing where this is going, in particular I don't see how to bring the prime condition into this?

Comment: Right, so effectively the annihilator of an element $x \in A/\mathfrak{a}$ is the ideal quotient $(0:x)$ (in the terminology of p8), where here we take the zero ideal $(0)$ to be the zero ideal in $A/\mathfrak{a}$. The radical of this annihilator is $r(0:x)$ in $A/\mathfrak{a}$. Things should be clear after this, when we pass out of the quotient.

Comment: On the first remark, perhaps the authors mean that use Lemma 4.4 ii) to conclude that $(\mathfrak{a}:x_i)=(\mathfrak{q}_i:x)$ is primary since having a prime radical does not imply that the ideal is primary, in general.